# iOS submission asking to use services which im not using?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

I have an app which was developed in `obj-c`. I have submitted the app earlier and I did some changes in the app(update admob) and re-submit. Now when it uploaded it says to add following key to `info.plist`.

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "ABC app". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value
>   explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.

Why should I add those keys, I am not using those services. And finally I have added those keys but not getting same email from Apple.

What can I do on this?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using some **Third Party SDKs** which are using **Calendar** and **Bluetooth** services. I also had same issue with one of my apps. I was using **Quickblox SDK** which uses Camera and Microphone services. So, I had to add the **Description Key** for those.